# Postgres query jsonb to extract value of one name:value pair based on value of a different name:value pair

Tags: json, regex, postgresql

I have a postgres table that is created using benthos.dev/Golang and cannot change how it is created.
This table has json data inserted into columns as strings.
A separate benthos yaml will query this using postgres.
For the select statement from that table, the intent is to find the element with a given name for "system" and return the value of the corresponding "value".  (not the value of system, the value of the element called "value")
All responses need to be on the same row.
Here is a mock up
Column name :  Suigeneris

| name | Suigeneris |
| --- | --- |
| baz | [{"system":"https://alpha.com/externalid","use":"home","value":"JJO5H0001"},{"system":"http://gee.org/berlin/uni/Suigeneris-num","use":"usual","value":"2122206077"}] |

The desired output from a select is

| name | Suigeneris | Sui-alpha | Sui-berlin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| baz | [{"system":"https://alpha.com/externalid","use":"home","value":"JJO5H0001"},{"system":"http://gee.org/berlin/uni/Suigeneris-num","use":"usual","value":"2122206077"}] | JJO5H0001 | 2122206077 |

I've tried two approaches and am using this query for advice on using postgres to select the desired data. I tried doing this in postgres by calculating the position of the {} and then using that to separate but this creates a difficult to read and easy to mess up long query.
example:

```
select substring (Suigeneris from (position ( '{' IN Suigeneris )) for (position ( '}' IN Suigeneris ))-(position ( '{' IN Suigeneris ))) 
from table
```

I only tried with the first position.
I also tried with regex_match and this works but does require that the order of the names is always the same (e.g. "system is first).  It looks like this is true but not sure what would happen if the source system decided to switch it.

```
SELECT (regexp_match(identifier,'("system":"http:\/\/gee.org\/berlin\/uni\/Suigeneris-num.*)(?=})')) as npi
FROM table
```

However, the problem is that I have to put that query into a YAML file and get 'unexpected scalar at node end' - I have tried escaping the double quotes with single '"'and double """ quotes.  Looking at the Yaml documentation, I am not understanding a solution.
The postgres query will go into a yaml file.

Note again that the intention is to read one name:value pair and extract the value from a different name:value pair in that object.  For "system": "https...alpha..." extract the value of "value".
Both solutions extract the whole sequence relating to one value with the intention of extracting the desired value in the next step.  But it would be ideal to get the value as described.  There is no reason to keep the entire object within the {}.

An option might be to get the lookahead match in regex to pick up the first bracket before the "berlin" text without specifying the entire string.  I have failed to find a way to position the regex at say "berlin" and find the first { before and after that as a match. That might allow not having the full https address and might solve the yaml scalar problem.

Or there might be a better way
using "PostgreSQL 14.2

Comment: Don't use regex. Use [JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)!

Comment: There were faqs relating to this in other threads, but they all seem to discuss xml or html.  I am guessing that regex isn't designed for json?  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The problems of processing XML with regex are the same as the problems of processing JSON with regex, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query for that:

```
select name, 
       "unique",
       jsonb_path_query_first("unique", '$[*] ? (@.system == "https://alpha.com/externalid").value') #>> '{}' as unique_alpha,
       jsonb_path_query_first("unique", '$[*] ? (@.system == "http://gee.org/berlin/uni/unique-num").value') #>> '{}' as unique_berlin
from the_table
```

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a `jsonb` value. Unfortunately there is no direct cast to text from `jsonb`. For that `#>> '{}'` is used.

Note that `unique` is a really bad choice for a column name, as that is a reserved keyword.

Comment: That isn't the real name of the column but I changed it in the example to Suigeneris. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.  I tried that and modified it to

Comment: sorry, modified to use \u0022 in place of quotes around http and modified to add ::jsonb to column because it is character varying in the table.  would love a breakdown of the regex.  @Bergi said not to use regex but this works!

Comment: validating that this works for me all the way.  Also acknowledging that your fern to is an a json path query, not regex.

Comment: "*because it is character varying in the table.*"  your question claims it's a `jsonb` column. And it **should** be one. In the long run it would be better to change the data type.